# How to return a value inside for loop in rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to port this python code

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def testing(x, y):
    for i in range(y):
        x = 2.0 * x
        if x > 3.5:
            return i
    return 999


for i in range(20):
    print testing(float(i) / 10, 15)
```

and its output

```
999
5
4
3
3
2
2
2
etc.
```

to rust code.  This is the rust code I wrote which is identical to the above python code.

```rust
fn testing(x: f32, y: i32) -> i32 {
    for i in 0..y {
        let x = 2.0 * x;
        if x > 3.5 {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 999;
}

fn main() {
    for i in 0..20 {
        let a = i as f32;
        println!("{}", testing(a / 10.0, 15));
    }
}
```

But its output is not the same as the python codes output

```
999
999
999
999
999
999
999
etc.
```

What is the right way to return a value in for loop using rust? Why is the my rust code outputting a different output comparing to pythons?

Comment: idiomatic code, two version: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=0fd68d7e3e003971b8ed7d35cad2b6b2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is the line

```rust
let x = 2.0 * x;
```

`let` introduces a new variable, the original `x` is not modified.
The next loop iteration will then again multiple 2.0 with the parameter `x`, not with the variable `x` from the previous loop's iteration.

You need to instead assign the value to the existing `x` variable (which requires marking it as `mut`able):

```rust
fn testing(mut x: f32, y: i32) -> i32 {
    for i in 0..y {
        x = 2.0 * x;
        if x > 3.5 {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 999;
}

fn main() {
    for i in 0..20 {
        let a = i as f32;
        println!("{}", testing(a / 10.0, 15));
    }
}
```